# How to get displayed text of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div just like this:

```
<div id="content" style="width:300px; height:500px; overflow:hidden">
   ...large text...  
</div>
```

I get the text in this div via the following code:

```
var text = $(content).html()
```

There is a lot of text in the div, and part of the text is hidden through `overflow:hidden`. I don't want to get all the text, but only the text that is currently visible in the div. How do I do that?

Comment: Try `.text()`, `$('#content').text()`, still the last part of your question is not clear

Comment: Your Question isn't clear. can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: You mean just the visible part of the text (while the rest of the text does not fit into the container)?

Comment: @ShaunakD op is speaking about the text which is not cut off from the div while using the property `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I think what you want to do is to use `substring()` The question isn't clear, but I think it's what should help.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, yeah You are right I guess.

Comment: what I meant is that, inside the content div there is al large text

Comment: @younes I have edited your question to make it more clear what you meant. If that isn't what you meant, feel free to revert it and edit the question yourself to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#content").text()
```

should give you the inner text of the `div` having the `id` of `content`.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the div with js, removed the overflow:hidden part for the clickable link and nest the content div within it:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<div class="content">
...large text...
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>





 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".content").hide();   //hide content on page load
         $(".show_hide").show(); //show the clickable link

     $('.show_hide').click(function(){
     $(".content").slideToggle(); // slideToggle() shows and hides
     });

 });

 </script>





 .content {
     Width: 300px;
     height:500px;
     background-color: #fff;
     Color: #000;
     margin-top:10px;
     border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
 }

 .show_hide {
     display:none;
 }
```

**edit**

Here let's say you have an  and a

inside the div

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
   function toggle() {
          var text = document.getElementById("#content p");
          if(text.style.display == "none") {
             text.style.display = "block";
             text.innerHTML = "show";
                }
          else {

               text.innerHTML = "hide";
          }
     } 
   </script>
```

Then just call the toggle function from within

Comment: Oops I might have misunderstood the question after reading new comments

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, can you maybe add more code? So you have a div with text hidden...

Comment: yes exactly, I have a div with text hidden, some text shown and other is hidden, the question is , I want to get just the shown text, I hope it's clear. thanks

Comment: Ok so both hidden and visible text are in 1 single div?

Comment: Check my edit. It would be very helpful if you provide much more code though